# How does Firebase identify my application and prevent other apps from impersonating my app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-security

I have created a project in Firebase and registered my app. I send data messages to this app. **I do not want to have any user authentication on my app. However, I do want that all my FCM data messages be handled only by my app. No other app be able to access my data messages.**

So, my question is - How does Firebase ensure that the app which is registering with my project is the intended app?

If it is based on package name, then I can very well create a dummy app and name it exactly the way as the app I'm trying to spoof. Isn't this a big security flaw?

I can decompile the APK to get all the required config for the google-services.json. So, what stops someone from tricking my Firebase project into registering their app and getting access to all the data messages?

I created a dummy app and was able to reproduce the above. The dummy app successfully received the data message.

I do see something called App ID for my app in the Firebase project settings, but this isn't something I provided while setup. So, this is something Firebase generated. So, this wouldn't be a way to verify the app I assume.

Comment: You're in charge of securing your database, whether it's RTDB or Firestore. If you don't have user accounts, [consider anonymous auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) and/or [AppCheck](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check). Note that your databases will still have a public URL, so will have to secure them with [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started).

Comment: I'm not using a database. All I'm using is data messages, which is a variant of notifications. My app server sends "notifications" to apps using deviceToken. I want to make sure that only my app receives that, not some dummy app.

Comment: Check, the question is about FCM. Noted.